# Cast MySQL Decimal data type type to c# float data type

Tags: c#, mysql, casting

I have a Decimal data type column in my MySQL database and i am reading it with `reader.Read()` in my C# code. Now I need to cast it to C# float data type. How can I do it:

`float fl = (float)reader[9];` throws `System.InvalidCastException`

Comment: What is the value of `reader[9]` exactly? What is your `CurrentCulture`? Use debugger.

Comment: What happens if you set  `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");`  in your code and try your original code again?

Comment: @juergend d System.InvalidCastException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`Convert.ToSingle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert.ToSingle(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
float fl = Convert.ToSingle(reader[9]);
```

Comment: This works but I want to obtain 236.89 not 236,89. Some edits in the code?

Comment: @gdrt94 If you are getting 236,89 instead of 236.89, then your culture settings for your machine are set to French or some other culture that uses "," for the decimal separator. You can see these settings in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats -> Additional settings... The field of interest is Decimal symbol. If you want to start handling regional differences, you may need to update your question.